# Calling "collapse" on bootstrap accordion in a modal prevents me from opening it again

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap/jquery. I have a modal window with a form in it, and the form contains an accordion group. I'd like to collapse everything in the accordion group each time the modal is opened. I've added the following code that executes when I click the button to open the modal:

```
$('.accordion-body').each(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('in')) {
        $(this).collapse('toggle');
    }
});
```

It works to collapse everything in the accordion group, but every accordion that has the collapse toggle called won't expand when clicked anymore. I get similar behavior replacing the code above with this:

```
$('.accordion-body').collapse();
```

In this case, since the collapse gets called on all the accordion bodies, nothing will expand.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't understand your question completly but I've created a fiddle with an example how I understand it.

[Demo Fiddle with modal](http://jsfiddle.net/TkU8k/2/)

Using both the:

```
data-toggle="collapse"
```

and

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function () {
  $('.accordion-body').each(function(){
        $(this).collapse();
});
})
```

Comment: Putting it in the .on("shown") works, which is what I was missing. However, your code expands every section the first time I open the modal. I tried setting them all to open on default, but then I get a quick flash of the content when I open the modal before they close. I tried doing $(this).collapse('hide'), but that had the same effect.